# camera2 api - not getting call back onImageAvailable in Moto Nexus

Tags: android

I am not getting callback onImageAvailable for Moto nexus 6.
I am trying to use camera api2 to capture images. The code worked fine on MOTO g4, but when I test the code on NEXUS 6, the onImageAvailable is not invoked after session.capture, and no image has been saved. Really frustrated, greatly appreciated if someone could help! Thanks so much.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=520, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/4988/ORIGINAL/NONE/989053760
>   flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list
>   U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F4988/ORIGINAL/NONE/989053760}
>   }} to activity {com.qopius/com.qopius.screens.cameraGrid.CameraAct}:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found
>   for UID 10744 and Uri 0 @
>   content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/4988/ORIGINAL/NONE/989053760

Comment: Do you have any logs ? Maybe you're using a feature or a parameter not available on Nexus 6

Comment: @Bruno please check now i have edited.

Comment: Are you asking permissions on runtime ? Since Android 6.0, you have to.

Comment: First check that have you used run time permission? Second if your target version is `>=24` then you need to use `FileProvider` to get uri path.